# nginx - how to create rails app without app name in domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I'm using nginx with passenger and I wanted to ask, how to create rails app, without showing app name in domain.
Currently I know how to setup nginx configuration with domain like this:

```
domain.com/app_name
```

and in the routes file when I create `root 'welcome#index'`
I still have to type `domain.com/app_name` to view my controller, but how to make it display welcome controller when the domain is simply `domain.com`

my nginx configuration looks looks this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name domain.com;
  root /home/username/rails;

    location ~ ^/app_name(/.*|$) {
      alias /home/username/rails/app_name/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'p$
      passenger_base_uri /app_name;
      passenger_app_root /home/username/rails/app_name;
      passenger_document_root /home/username/rails/app_name/public;
      passenger_app_env development;
      passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

when I try to comment out `#passenger_base_uri /app_name` I got 403 ERROR code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `location` block, `alias`, `passenger_base_uri`, `passenger_app_root`, and `passenger_document_root`. Change `root` to your Rails `public` directory too. It should look like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name domain.com;
  root /home/username/rails/app_name/public;

  passenger_app_env development;
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Try to follow this example of this production nginx config, which also includes some best practices for configuring your server: https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/711913

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did as you said and removed all the things, but I also added

`root /home/username/rails/app_name/public;`

and now it's working.